# solr upgrade from 3.x to 4.7 schema.xml

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am working solr environment which is running on 3.x. Now I am migrating it to solr 4.7

I have done all the required changes but need a work around or a solution for one.

In schema.xml I have copyField,

```
<copyField source="startIpNum" dest="startIp"/>

<uniqueKey>startIp</uniqueKey> 

<defaultSearchField>locId</defaultSearchField> 

<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

The field's are defined like below.

```
<field name="startIp" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true"/>
<field name="startIpNum" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true"/>
```

I get the below exception after starting the solr env.

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: uniqueKey field (startIp) can not be the dest of a copyField(source=startIpNum). Schema file is /qv/tst/solr/qvprlsolrextB/solr/geo/schema.xml.

Other than this all other stuff are in place. I have totally 14 cores, all of them working other than this one which use copyField. Is this deprecated in 4.7?

Any information is helpful.

Thanks
SR

Comment: Have you tried to define startIpNum as unique key instead?

Comment: agree, it's really weird to do that

Comment: The exception is rather clear. You have defined a field as uniqueKey that is target of a copyField directive. You are not allowed to do that. That has nothing to do with deprecation of the copyField.

Comment: The reason I said deprecated is with `<copyField source="startIpNum" dest="startIp"/>` it works fine in 3.x

Comment: I put the copyField inside the <fields> </fields> and kept ` <uniqueKey>startIpNum</uniqueKey>` as mentioned by leo and is working fine.